# fastest way to get eigenvalues of many 1d array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, eigenvalue, abaqus

I have a (n, m, 6)-array with n and m being more than 10.000. The 6 values are from a symmetric matrix in following order:

[[11, 12, 13], [12, 22, 23], [13, 23, 33]]  => (11, 22, 33, 12, 23, 31)

What I want to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of every matrix. Right now it's implemented with 2 for-loops iterating each dimension, reordering the values into matrix form and calculating the eigenvalues. But I wonder if there is a much faster solution using vectorization?

Comment: Postprocessing `abaqus` output are we?

Comment: Yes, that's the way the results are stored...

Comment: Added the `abaqus` tag as this is a pretty common problem I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I've found is to use a `(6,3,3)` transform matrix to turn the symmetric values into a proper symmetric tensor.

```
transf = np.array([[[1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]],                #11
                   [[0.,0.,0.],[0.,1.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]],                #22
                   [[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,1.]],                #33
                   [[0.,1.,0.],[1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]],                #12 & 21
                   [[0.,0.,1.],[0.,0.,0.],[1.,0.,0.]],                #13 & 31
                   [[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,1.],[0.,1.,0.]]]).swapaxes(0,1) #23 & 32

e, v = np.linalg.eigh(input.dot(transf))
```

NON-PROGRAMMING NOTE:  Be careful about whether `abaqus` is outputting real stress/strain or engineering stress/strain, as the resulting transform is different (if I remember correctly for for "real strain" you need the off-diagonal terms to be `0.5` instead of `1.`)

Comment: Sry, it took me some time to test it but now I did and it just works perfectly and is much faster than my loop solution. Thank you so much.
I want also to thank you for the output advice. I had already problems with that but got it fixed!